# CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD when updating Contact's AccountId in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, accountcontactrelation

I have a flow that, in the end, updates AccountId to empty string and it was working fine but now is giving me the following error:

```
CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD: Before you can make this contact private, you must remove its relationships to other accounts
```

This is my UpdateRecords' screen:
[image]

I also tried updating the AccountContactRelationship record (because we have multiple contacts to account enabled) but no luck:

[image]

[image]

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an empty string, "not null"?

Comment: @PhilW because I want to set AccountId as a null value and I can't relate it to null, only to empty string

Comment: AFAIK you can set the `AccountId` as `null` by simply not defining a "Value" in the "Set Field Values for the Contact Records", where you define what to set the `AccountId` Field to. That's why there's a special "empty string (not null)" global value, to explicitly use an empty string rather than the (default) null value. But you don't need that here.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD: Before you can make this contact private, you must remove its relationships to other accounts" occurs when you are trying to update a Contact record in Salesforce and set the AccountId field to null, but the Contact record is still associated with other Account records.

This error message is telling you that before you can set the AccountId field to null, you must first remove any existing relationships between the Contact record and other Account records. This means that you will need to update any Account records that are related to the Contact record and remove the Contact's ID from the related list of Contacts on those Account records.

Once you have removed the relationships between the Contact record and other Account records, you should be able to update the Contact record and set the AccountId field to null without encountering the error message.

Comment: The related `Contact`s appear in a list on the `Account` because of the `AccountId` on the `Contact` records. What you have described is purely chicken and egg. I suspect the problem is actually because of use of `AccountContactRole` junction records that need to be removed first...